# create-react-app using npx generating error message path not found

Tags: create-react-app

After running following command i am getting error

```
npx create-react-app
```

> "$basedir/../../Users/abc/AppData/Local/Yarn/.global/node_modules/.bin/create-react-app.cmd"   "$@"
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

node and NPM versions

```
λ node -v
v9.5.0

λ npm -v
5.6.0
```

Comment: I have also tried with npm -g intall create-react-app, when i am going to create the application, same error showing on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and some digging, I finally found the solution. I installed yarn before, so it was mixing something up...

```
create-react-app command was still working when i completely removed it form my PC.
```

In short create-react-app.cmd file was reside in ProgramFils\nodjs folder I don't know why/how this file was there. After removing the creat-react-app command file all was set.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. I solved this by using yarn instead of npx:

```
yarn create react-app [name of app]
```

Note there is no hyphen between create and react-app